# ERROR! no action detected in task. Ansible

Tags: nginx, ansible

I recently started using Ansible and I have a playbook file, the content is the following:

```
...# Code to start an EC2 instance in the same playbook
...# Then trying to install Nginx on the same server:

  - hosts: webserver
    become: yes
    remote_user: ubuntu
    tasks:
      - name: Install Nginx
        apt: pkg=nginx state=installed update_cache=true
        notify:
          - start nginx
```

And I am geting the following error when running it with

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts ec2_launch.yml
```

**ERROR! no action detected in task. his often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.**

```
The offending line appears to be:

  - hosts: webserver
    ^ here
```

I must be missing something there, cannot figure out what to update. Maybe I cannot start the instance and install Nginx in the same playbook?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. The error is probably in the section before, the one that actually creates the instance

Comment: OK so yes, I realised I had put these tasks below the EC2 provisioning ones, so I moved them and this error is no longer. Now, the issue is that it still does not install Nginx as it says `PLAY [Install Nginx on this new instance] **************************************
skipping: no hosts matched`. Though I have a task that add the newly created EC2 instance to the hosts file.

Comment: I think you should add the ec2 provision task to make the question clearer. Also, there's a lot of examples in the ec2 module [Ansible Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html) on how to run tasks on newly created instances.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the documentation, there was something I needed to amend with:
  `- name: Add new instance to host group
        add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=launched
        with_items: ec2.instances`

Answer (score -2):

Updating this to show how this issue got resolved:

```
---
  - name: Provision an EC2 Instance
    hosts: local
    connection: local
    gather_facts: True
    tags: provisioning
    # Necessary Variables for creating/provisioning the EC2 Instance
    vars:
      instance_type: t2.micro
      security_group: Webserver  # Change the security group name here
      image: amiID # Change the AMI, from which you want to launch the server
      region: eu-central-1 # Change the Region
      keypair: keypair # Change the keypair name
      count: 1

    # Task that will be used to Launch/Create an EC2 Instance
    tasks:
      - name: Launch the new EC2 Instance
        local_action: ec2 
                      group={{ security_group }} 
                      instance_type={{ instance_type}} 
                      image={{ image }} 
                      wait=true 
                      region={{ region }} 
                      keypair={{ keypair }}
                      count={{count}}
        register: ec2

      - name: Add new instance to host group
        add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=launched
        with_items: ec2.instances

      - name: Wait for SSH to come up
        local_action: wait_for 
                      host={{ item.public_ip }} 
                      port=22 
                      state=started
        with_items: ec2.instances

      - name: Add tag to Instance(s)
        local_action: ec2_tag resource={{ item.id }} region={{ region }} state=present
        with_items: ec2.instances
        args:
          tags:
            Name: webserver

  - name: Install Nginx on this new instance
    hosts: launched
    become: yes
    remote_user: ubuntu
    tasks:
      - name: Install Nginx
        apt: pkg=nginx state=installed update_cache=true
        notify:
          - start nginx
```

With the latest Ansible updates, this triggers some warning and will require a playbook update but this is the current implementation I used to solve the above issue, based on the comments.